# How can I offset my col so that links can be clickable?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating an "app-like" menu bar for a website in mobile version only.  This bar has two clickable icons and one main button in the center. Even though I managed to write the html/css, I can not click the icons because the "+" button is on top of the icons. Is there a way I can arrange this so that the user is able to click the menu, plus and user's icon?

This is my design:

[image]

I managed to created this design with the following code (I'm using Bootstrap 4 and Fontawesome)

```css
.footer-container-mobile {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: #8ABE57;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px -4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.footer-container-mobile i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.circle-btn-mobile {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #31353C;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47));
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.circle-btn-mobile-container {
  z-index: 50;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row d-flex footer-container-mobile">
    <a href="#" class="mr-auto"><i class="far fa-bars"></i>Icon</a>
    <a href="#" class="ml-auto"><i class="fas fa-user-plus">Icon</i></a>
  </div>

  <div class="row circle-btn-mobile-container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-auto circle-btn-mobile">
      <i class="far fa-plus">+</i>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `width: fit-content;` css for `circle-btn-mobile-container` container, and `m-auto` class as follows to make `margin: auto;`:

```
<div class="row circle-btn-mobile-container m-auto">
```

```css
.footer-container-mobile {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 54px;
  background-color: #8ABE57;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  box-shadow: 0px -4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.footer-container-mobile i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.circle-btn-mobile {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #31353C;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 2em;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.47));
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.circle-btn-mobile-container {
  width: fit-content;
  z-index: 50;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row d-flex footer-container-mobile">
    <a href="#" class="mr-auto"><i class="far fa-bars"></i>Icon</a>
    <a href="#" class="ml-auto"><i class="fas fa-user-plus">Icon</i></a>
  </div>

  <div class="row circle-btn-mobile-container m-auto">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-auto circle-btn-mobile">
      <i class="far fa-plus">+</i>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```